# Solve 3 exponential equations $z^x=x$, $z^y=y$, $y^y=x$ to get $x$, $y$, $z$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, systems-of-equations

The main question is :

$z^x=x$, $z^y=y$, $y^y=x$

Find $z$, $y$, $x$.

My method :

I first attempted to get two equation for the unknowns $x$ and $y$.

We can happily write :

$z=x^{1/x}$ and $z=y^{1/y}$

Thus we get,
$x^{1/x}=y^{1/y}$
Which is,
$x^y=y^x$.

I can't go any farther than this. Please help me.

Comment: $z^x\ne zx$ so I'm not sure dividing is a good idea.

Comment: Im not able to put fractions in the indices

Comment: Try z^{1/x} between dollar signs.

Comment: I would not use \frac inside the exponent and make sure the exponent is wrapped in {}. Also your last equation should be substituted in your last step to get $x=y^2$ I think.

Comment: Yeah I got it. Thanks @John Molokach

Comment: I have removed (inequality) tag, since the question does not seem to be about inequalities. (But if I missed something, feel free to edit it back.)

Comment: Yeah it doesn't. I forgot to remove the tag, I had previously asked a question related to inequalities. Thanks @Martin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$z^{y}=y$$
$$(z^y)^y=y^y$$
$$z^{y^2}=x=z^x$$
therefore
$$x=y^2$$
on the other hand
$$y^y=x=y^2\implies y=2$$
thus
$$x=4\quad,\quad z=\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Gee, I was pretty close. Thanks @Behrouz

Comment: The argument that $z^{y^2}=z^x$ implies $y^2=x$ works for $z\ne1$. So probably some trivial solutions should be added. (At least $x=y=z=1$ seems to work. And this is probably the only solution with $z=1$.)

Comment: Yes. It is trivial

Comment: You forgot to consider extra solutions when you assume $x=y^2$, as there is the trivial but less obvious $x=y=z=-1$.  Be careful $\log$-ing both sides, and consider periodicity.  More generally, consider $|z|=1$ and $z\in\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 3):

One solution just by looking at it is $z=x=y=1$.

Comment: Yes, I guessed that. But I wasn't sure whether there would be any other solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

And to be different, the third solution is $x=y=z=-1$, by old-fashioned trial and error.

Comment: No, -1 cannot be an answer. Observe that x and y are bases and by definition cannot be negative.

Comment: @AksharGandhi What?!  No way!  As far as I've ever heard, $(-1)^n$ is fully defined for $n\in\mathbb Z$, I've never seen someone say that.  If $n\in\mathbb R$, maybe, but not in $\mathbb Z$.  For example,$$(-1)^{-1}=\frac1{-1}=-1$$I'm pretty sure everyone defines powers this way.

Comment: My professor said so. I will ask him again, now that you place such a steong argument.

Comment: @AksharGandhi Your professor probably said something more along the lines of $x^n$ is not defined for negative $x$ as a graph/function, but that is only because $(-1)^{1/2}$ makes no sense, for example, in this context.  As for individual values, like in this problem, negative bases can have meaning.